# Morphia give "Possible heterogenous collection" warning for a Map field

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have an entity class as follows:

```
@Entity(noClassnameStored = true)
public class DataMart implements Serializable {
    private ObjectId id;
    private String name;
        .
        .
        .
        .
    private Map<String, Object> validTimeRangeOfExistingData;
}
```

I am using Morphia to fetch records of this Model. I am using **morphia-1.00-SNAPSHOT.jar** from Play 1.2.7 distribution.
I am seeing a lot of Warning messages with following text in Console log.

> [java] WARNING: The multi-valued field
>   'model.DataMart.validTimeRangeOfExistingData' is a
>   possible heterogenous collection. It cannot be verified. Please
>   declare a valid type to get rid of this warning. class
>   java.lang.Object

Is there any way to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: In queries you can disable validation: https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/wiki/Query#disabling-validation. I'm not sure about plain objects in entities — could you wrap it in a custom class?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @xeraa.

I am trying to avoid it at the moment, since it requires a lot of rewrites in the code. Reason being that we are trying to put another map as value here.

If there is no other option, I will try as suggested.

Comment: @xeraa , adding validation didn't help. I am still getting same warnings